# Is it possible to monitor a file in multiple projects with Git?

Tags: git

Suppose you have multiple applications that rely on the same library file and this file is changed somewhere. Is it possible to link these projects in a way that the file will be updated in all of them? Or if that is not possible is there a way to at least get notified about the change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what submodules are for, if your project depends on an independently-updated history, track it with a submodule, i.e. link that history and say where to find a repo that has it.